# What's the best pattern for if-statement blocks for returning?

Tags: python, python-3.x

They're the same logic, but I was wondering what's better between the two whether readability/for future iteration/etc, on any dimension of software engineering or best coding practices.

```
def is_setting_enabled(a):
    if a == "green":
        return is_green_setting_enabled()
    if a == "blue":
        return is_blue_setting_enabled()
    if a == "yellow":
        return is_yellow_setting_enabled()
    return False
```

or

```
def is_setting_enabled(a):
    if a == "green":
        return is_green_setting_enabled()
    elif a == "blue":
        return is_blue_setting_enabled()
    elif a == "yellow":
        return is_yellow_setting_enabled()
    return False
```

Comment: the first one is more pythonic. In fact, many linters will complain about the second one

Answer (score 1):

What if I said neither:

```
color_fn_map = {
    "green": is_green_setting_enabled,
    "blue": is_blue_setting_enabled,
    "yellow": is_yellow_setting_enabled,
}
def is_setting_enabled(a):
    return color_fn_map.get(a, lambda: False)()
```

Easy to extend, mapping is clear, and if you end up having a lot of colors this will be faster than the ifs.

I don't think this is categorically better, but I like it more when there are lots of possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, I've obfuscated and oversimplified the code and won't be as simple to map colors to color-based functions

Comment: unrelated to the question, but that will kick back if the result of any of these functions can change at runtime

Comment: woops, you're right @Marat, meant to remove the function calls but left them in dictionary, updating coming